# formatting string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

I've a predefined string format. For instance '>>>,>>>,>>9.99' this means that the  system should display string in this '500,000,000.10'. The format can change based on the users using it. How can I write a common function to display stings on the given format passing
the input value and the format as the parameter using C#

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ToString` method with a [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) or [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
string format = "{0:000,000,000.00}";
string val = 12.3456;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format, value)); // it prints "000,000,123.23"
```

You can read more about formating values here http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal value = 1.2345; 
string rounded = value.ToString("d2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private string sDecimalFormat = "0.00";

decimal d = 120M;

txtText.Text = d.ToString(sDecimalFormat);
```

You could then have a setting for decimal format eg:

```
txtText.Text = d.ToString(Settings.DecimalFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

String.formate can be used for formating.

Go there if you want examples
http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Answer (score 0):

I think the following might work:

```
String result = String.Format(fmt.Replace('>', '#').Replace('9', '0'), inpString);
```

`fmt` being the format you want to use and `inpString` being the string entered by the user.

Just replace the `>` with `#` and the `9` with `0` and it'll be a valid .Net formatstring.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`Format` method on `String`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx)

```
String.Format("{0:X}", 10); // prints A (hex 10)
```

There are several methods to format [numbers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx), [date](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)...

Answer (score 0):

I dont seem to understand how you can make 500,000,000.10 from >>>,>>>,>>9.99' but I believe the answer would be

But I assume something you are looking for is: `string.Format("500,000,00{0:0.##}", 9.9915)`

You can then make a method like

```
Public string GetString(string Format, object value)
{
     return string.Format(Format, value);
}
```

Something like this?

Comment: why would you need a "GetString" method to call string.format with the exact same parameters?

Comment: because the TS asked how to write a common function.